# To fetch fields requires the name of the table as a parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to get the table structure of my database tables. SO i am using the below code.

```
class Some_model extends CI_Model{

    public $DB1;
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->DB1 = $this->load->database('default',TRUE);
    }

    function getTableStructure($tableName){
        echo $tableName;     //this Outputs my table Name that i pass in the function
        return $this->DB1->field_data($tableName) ;   //this gives error for some tables
    }
}
```

I get a Database Error

*To fetch fields requires the name of the table as a parameter.*

**Note :** This function works on some tables but i get this error on few other tables.   Table i am checking on is "admin_user"

**Update :**

I have checked the field_data function in the DB_driver.php file in the system/database folder.

when i print the return object i.e

```
echo "<pre">;print_r($query->field_data());die();
//return $query->field_data();   commented this line print's the object
```

However,

```
//echo "<pre">;print_r($query->field_data());die();  comment this line shows error. 
return $query->field_data();
```

Comment: are you making sure you are not using capital letters for your table names? Keep in mind this is case-sensitive

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: tablename is same as passed in the function.
I get a DB Error : To fetch fields requires the name of the table as a parameter.

Comment: you say this: _"this gives error for some tables"_ For the tables that you get the error, can you provide the table name string you are using?

Comment: the table name is "admin_user"

Comment: `$query->field_data('admin_user');`

Comment: It's hard to re-produce the same problem because the code should work and working.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why don't you use default DB configuration by calling

```
$this->db->field_data($tableName);
```

instead custom variable DB1 since you don't change connection, db or anything shown or mentioined in question.
However, next code would work like a charm:

```
public function desc1($tableName)
{
    $fields = $this->db->field_data($tableName);
    var_dump($fields);
}
```

or even you can use custom query like:

```
public function desc2($tableName)
{
    $fields = $this->db->query("DESCRIBE `" . $tableName . "`");
    var_dump($fields->result());
}
```

Those two functions are slightly different in returned results so you have to check both of them and see what would better suit to your code (i.e. custom one gives extra field too).

Comment: I agree @Tpojka  I removed my answer because of that was not fair down vote with out telling why

Comment: This answer does not explain why Op got error for some tables and `I am not sure why don't you use default DB configuration by calling` this should be asked in comment section not in answer.

Comment: His pointing of DB1 doesn't make sense, but I will take your opinion for future.

Answer (score 1):

Work fine for me .

```
function getTableStructure($tableName){
  if(isset($tableName)){
     return $this->db->field_data($tableName) ;
     }
 }
```

check! and make sure there is no keyword used as field name in your table.

Comment: i see ,but you are not using default `db->field` ,
if your method work on some tables ,and not on admin_user then answer cannot be possible .i would suggest you to provide admin_user table structure also .

Comment: I used `$this->db->field_data($tableName)` and you overwrote it with `$this->db->field_data($tableName)`? What are you talking about? Please, explain or read my answer again.

Comment: there is clear and much deference between your answer and mine,
i also up-voted your answer .
but in question he says **To fetch fields requires the name of the table as a parameter.**
so there is need of `isset($tableName)` and i added.

Comment: OP asked why he got this error( `To fetch fields requires the name of the table as a parameter.`) for some tables and this answer does not provide any reason instead of saying it works for me. and this should be comment `check! and make sure there is no keyword used as field name in your table.`

Answer (score 0):

The error message says what you missed.
Your $tableName is empty when you got that error.
You can look at `system/database/DB_driver.php`  and look at `field_data`(line 878 may be) function. You get that error message when your `$table`(tablename)is empty.
Make sure your table name is not empty.

Comment: according to @BadDeveloper he is already using this `echo $tableName;` to test the string, so this might not be culprit.

Comment: @CodeGodie That error message only shows when you set empty table name. Otherwise OP's output should be `THE_TABLE_NAME then the error message`. But It does not prints the table name because tablename is empty. If he echo like this `echo 'abc-'.$tableName.'-xyz';` he will understand what's going on.

Comment: well he echo `$tableName` so he knows ,table name is not empty .

Comment: @AbdulManan did you checked CI library?why that error message shows?You should look that first.And for OPs case its hard to reproduce that error unless we see his db and his code.He should debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your three file code with this link

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/effd0133b3fa805e21ec934196e8e7d75608ba00

files are:-

> system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_result.php
>
> system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_result.php
>
> user_guide_src/source/changelog.rst

Comment: SO discourage link only answer.Also this answer does not provide any reason why should he need replace the files and why will solve the problem.